# Iterating through multiple urls

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

With your help, I was able to get a scraper running, but now I am stuck when it comes to iterating.  Ultimately, I want to scraper to run through different URLs, but I'm getting confused in the syntax.  I am using Selenium to open the web page and then BeautifulSoup to extract the data.  I *think* I need to define the URLs and then use something like:

```
for url in urls
```

but I am not sure how to use this.  Reading other answers and videos has left me scratching my head.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import csv
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd

urls = ["https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/English/Racing/LocalResults.aspx?RaceDate=2021/02/06&Racecourse=ST&RaceNo=1","https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/English/Racing/LocalResults.aspx?RaceDate=2021/02/06&Racecourse=ST&RaceNo=2"]
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(urls)

for url in urls:
    html = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "f_fs13")))
htmlStr = driver.page_source

soup_level1 = soup(htmlStr, 'html.parser')

race_soup = soup_level1.find('tbody',{'class':'f_fs13'}).find_parent('table')
results_soup = soup_level1.find('tbody',{'class':'f_fs12'}).find_parent('table')

df1 = pd.read_html(str(race_soup))[0]
print(df1)


df2 = pd.read_html(str(results_soup))[0]
print(df2)


print('good')


driver.close()
```

Comment: you would rather need to put almost all of the code inside the `for url in urls:` loop starting from `driver.get(urls)` and ending with `print('good')`. But, if your plan is really to extend it later for additional urls and elements in a page, then better have a look into `scrapy`: https://scrapy.org/

Comment: You should also show what your expected output should be. Currently you are just printing results. Are you hoping to write this to a file somehow?

Comment: Hi @MartinEvans.  Yes, eventually.  I would like to scrape the data from a number of different URLs, save them to one data frame and export that to a CSV or directly to a SQL database.  In an old version, I had the data exported to a CSV, but I wanted to just print the data frame for now so I can see if it was being collected first.  One step at a time.

Comment: As suggested, first just indent all of your code the same under the `for` loop. Also move your `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` inside the loop and change the next line to `driver.get(url)`

Comment: @MartinEvans is right. Your code looks fine, just indent